# dropdown multiple options issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

I have a list of contacts, I would like to display the phoneNumbers in inputs with dropdown.

```
<div id="retrievedContactsDiv" data-bind="foreach: Model.userContacts.contacts()">

 <!-- ko if: ($data.phoneNumbers().length >= 1) -->
            <div class="control-group span3 offset3 ">

    <div class="input-append btn-group">

        <input  id="appendedInputButton"  type="text" data-bind="value:$data.phoneNumbers()[0].phoneNumber()">
        <a class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
            <span class="caret"></span>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <!-- ko foreach: $data.phoneNumbers() -->
            <li><span  data-bind="text: $data.phoneNumber()"></span> </li>
             <!-- /ko -->

        </ul>
    </div>

        </div>
        <!-- /ko -->
 </div>
```

JS

```
$('.dropdown-menu li span').click(function(){
    var elementVal=$(this).text();
        $('#appendedInputButton').val('');
    $('#appendedInputButton').val(elementVal);
    });
```

My problem is that I can't have same id, if I use class all the phoneNumbers of my contacts list will be modified, How can I do it to display correct value if the user use dropdown ?
http://imageup.fr/uploads/1377867794.jpeg

Comment: Please stop using jQuery todo Knockouts work, its so much worse at doing it

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery smart selectors to find the closest common parent and then find the field inside it.

```
$('.dropdown-menu li span').click(function(){
  var elementVal = $(this).text();

  $(this).closest('.input-append').find('#appendedInputButton').val(elementVal);
});
```

Actually this is also wrong (in terms of HTML) because you're stuck with duplicate IDs. I would rather suggest you do the same with a class instead of id, it'll work exactly the same with the suggested JS above.

Comment: Thx for answer. I have tried your js but when I click on dropdown option, input value is not updated. I have changed  id="appendedInputButton" to class

Comment: Solved  correct code  : 

` $(this).closest('.input-append').find('.appendedInputButton').val(elementVal);`